# How to use JS to detect words "orphaned" on a line by themselves at the end of a fixed-width div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typography

*I'm not sure "orphaned" is appropriate, but it's the best I could come up with here.*

I want to be able to detect when there's an additional word or two in the last line at the end of the text in a div.

**PLEASE NOTE: I am not trying to eliminate these "orphans" by giving them the company of another word on the final line.**

I've got a div with a fixed width that contains text that I need to end evenly at the end of a line. Sometimes a word (or two) creeps down to an additional line. I'd like to be able to detect when this happens (so the code can then adjust the font-size of the div until the orphan word/words pop up to the previous line).

Using `text-align-last: justify;` is not a solution to my problem by itself.

I've been trying `element.getClientRects()`, figuring I would get a rectangle for each row and then just look at the width of the lowest rectangle given. But for a single div, I get only one rectangle. And if I put the text inside a span inside the div, I get sometimes as many as nine rectangles for six lines of text in the span. Yikes! I have no idea what these rectangles represent.

Anyone know a way I can detect an extra isolated word on a line by itself at the end of the multi-line text in a fixed-width div?

---

### Addition

**PLEASE NOTE: the optimal number of lines is not known ahead of time; it could be anywhere from one to five lines.**

I've been asked to give examples.

Example 1 shows are three lines, but should be two lines:
[image: Example 1 includes indent]

```
<div class="chunk" style="text-indent:45ex;">
<div class="bekkerLine">25</div>
<span>τὸ μὲν οὖν εἰ ἓν καὶ ἀκίνητον τὸ ὂν σκοπεῖν οὐ περὶ φύσεος ἐστι σκοπεῖν·</span>
</div>
```

$0.getClientRects() on the span returns:

```
DOMRectList {0: DOMRect, 1: DOMRect, 2: DOMRect, 3: DOMRect, length: 4}
0: DOMRect {x: 475.796875, y: 328.875, width: 60.609375, height: 22, top: 328.875, …}
1: DOMRect {x: 536.40625, y: 328.875, width: 48.21875, height: 22, top: 328.875, …}
2: DOMRect {x: 139, y: 352.875, width: 445.546875, height: 22, top: 352.875, …}
3: DOMRect {x: 139, y: 376.875, width: 65.109375, height: 22, top: 376.875, …}
length: 4
__proto__: DOMRectList
```

Example 2 also shows as three lines and again should be two lines:
[image]

```
<div class="chunk">
<span> οὔ)· ἄνθρωπος γὰρ ἵππου ἕτερον τῷ εἴδει καὶ
 τἀναντία ἀλλήλων. 
 καὶ πρὸς Παρμενίδην δὲ ὁ αὐτὸς τρόπος τῶν λόγων,
 <div class="bekkerLine">22</div>
</span></div>
```

$0.getClientRects() on the span returns:

```
DOMRectList {0: DOMRect, 1: DOMRect, 2: DOMRect, 3: DOMRect, 4: DOMRect, length: 5}
0: DOMRect {x: 123, y: 319.875, width: 375.5, height: 22, top: 319.875, …}
1: DOMRect {x: 498.5, y: 319.875, width: 70.203125, height: 22, top: 319.875, …}
2: DOMRect {x: 123, y: 343.875, width: 82.40625, height: 22, top: 343.875, …}
3: DOMRect {x: 205.40625, y: 343.875, width: 363.46875, height: 22, top: 343.875, …}
4: DOMRect {x: 123, y: 367.875, width: 53.578125, height: 22, top: 367.875, …}
length: 5
__proto__: DOMRectList
```

Example 3 I wouldn't want to "fix" because the final line has too many words:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a code snippet with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two solutions that were posted didn't quite fit what I needed. (The way I wrote may be partially to blame. In any event I voted each of them up.) I ended up writing my own method for calculating the number of lines that the div should take up.

I put a span inside the div. This method sums the width of the client rects at each y position in order to get the length of each line of the span (not sure why these are divided up in the first place, but they are!). It then counts the number of these rects that are less than half the width of the div and returns that as the optimal number of lines.

```
howManyLinesIsBest(divEl) {
    const rect0 = (divEl.getClientRects())[0];
    const width = rect0.width;
    const span = (divEl.getElementsByTagName("span"))[0];
    const lines = {};
    [].forEach.call(span.getClientRects(),
      v => {
        if (lines.hasOwnProperty(v.y)) {
          lines[v.y] += v.width;
          return;
        }
        lines[v.y] = v.width;
      }
    );
    const wideRects = Object.values(lines).filter(v => v > width/2);
    return wideRects.length > 1 ? wideRects.length : 1;
  }
```

It works pretty well!

Comment: After posting this, I noticed some weird behavior: when you give the span's border a finite width, the client rects join together so the number of rects matches the number of lines! And they remain that way even after you turn the border off. Nevertheless the posted solution is robust against this change.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**: Now  the solution detects if there's `THRESHOLD` number of words on the last line. Here I set `THRESHOLD` to `2`. For the second div it ends with three words on the last line and doesn't change. For the third div it ends with one word on the last line and shrinks down. In the fourth div it starts with two words on the last line and shrinks.

```js
const THRESHOLD = 2;

document.querySelectorAll("div.fixed").forEach(el => {
  const { height: originalHeight } = el.getClientRects()[0];
  let thresholdIndex;
  for (let i = el.innerHTML.length, occurences = 0; i > 0; i--) {
    if (el.innerHTML[i] === " ") {
      occurences++;
    }
    if (occurences === THRESHOLD) {
      thresholdIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (thresholdIndex) {
    const lastWords = el.innerHTML.substring(
      thresholdIndex,
      el.innerHTML.length
    );
    const text = el.innerHTML.substring(0, thresholdIndex);
    el.innerHTML = text;
    const { height: newHeight } = el.getClientRects()[0];
    el.innerHTML += lastWords;
    if (newHeight < originalHeight) {
      let height = originalHeight;
      while (height > newHeight) {
        const currentFontSize = parseInt(
          window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("font-size"),
          10
        );
        const newFontSize = currentFontSize - 1;
        el.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
        height = el.getClientRects()[0].height;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
<div class="fixed">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
<div class="fixed">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
<div class="fixed">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be changing the font size. I'm asking about *detecting* whether there's an extra word on the last line. Also these divs could be any number of lines, up to five high.

Comment: _so the code can then adjust the font-size of the div until the orphan word/words pop up to the previous line_ What did you mean by this? You don't want to change the font size?

Comment: This solution is independent of number of lines (number of `div.fixed` that is)

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I'm not *asking* about that part. That's why it's in parentheses. I know very well how to do that part. I'm asking about the part that's not in parentheses. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Notice that another case would be if you had enough text to almost reach an entire two lines. Would your routine reduce the font size until the two lines fit on one? Perhaps I'm misreading, but it would seem so.

Comment: Yes, this solution adjusts the font-size until the `div.fixed` is one line. I think you need to add an example to your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Believe it or not, it takes a finite amount of time to give examples. I have now done so, thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to get at with that comment 

Comment: @JohnK adjusted to the further information you supplied

Answer (score 1):

I found a sort of answer to your question from another site:

"wrap every single character in a `<span>` and then loop through these `<span>`s, checking the offsetTop value for each.".

In your case you only care if the last third element is above the last since you want to know if the last two words are hanging.

I made this little snippet to show how it works: (going from 208 to 209 should produce a change)

```js
var paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph");
var thirdLast = document.getElementById("third-last");
var last = document.getElementById("last");
var widthSelector = document.getElementById("width");

function handleWidth(){
  var fontSize = 16;
  paragraph.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
  var width = widthSelector.value;
  paragraph.style.width = width + "px";
  while(thirdLast.offsetTop < last.offsetTop && fontSize > 0){
    fontSize--;
    paragraph.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="width" type="number" onchange="handleWidth()"/>

<p id="paragraph">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
anim <span id="third-last">id</span> 
est <span id="last">laborum.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Quite clever, and almost what I need. Thank you!

Comment: One remaining problem here is how to *automatically* create the internal spans. @Mohm's present answer does that, albeit imperfectly.

Comment: @JohnK You could get the innerText of the paragraph and split by spaces then modify the third last and last words by surrounding them with spans as above and replace the innerHtml of the paragraph with this modified text. I can update my answer if this sounds like what you're looking for